# laravel 5 restful methods in controller are missing

Tags: php, laravel-5

Following Laravel 5.2 documentation
I execute below line in command prompt of windows 7 to create the controller

```
php artisan make:controller UserController
```

`UserController.php` is created successfully.
However unlike the description in documentation, the `UserController.php` don't contains restful methods.

The file looks like this

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    //
}
```

How can I create the controller and contains `RESTFUL` methods by default?

Comment: I am not sure what could be the reason but happen to me quite a few times sometimes default views/controllers are missing at project creation time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resource controllers make it painless to build RESTful controllers around resources. For example, you may wish to create a controller that handles HTTP requests regarding "photos" stored by your application. Using the make:controller Artisan command, we can quickly create such a controller:

```
php artisan make:controller PhotoController --resource
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers

Comment: Yes it works. Wonder why the tuorial do not include --resource parameter.

Comment: It's on the 5.2 doc.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5.1 and below, by default the **make:controller** command used to generate the Controller with all required methods such as 'index, create, store, show, edit, update, destroy'. And for 5.1 and below, to have the blank controller file without any methods, we used to use '--plain' parameter as

```
php artisan make:controller --plain NAME_OF_CONTROLLER
```

But with Laravel 5.2, as explained by @Zeeshan, by default the artisan command will create the bare controller file without any RESTful methods.

As Laravel 5.2 has many changes, it is better to use the 'artisan help' command as below

```
php artisan help make:controller
```

With this, we will realize the introduction of `--resource`